# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS won't boot with USB ( Windows )

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

Alright, sorry if this was already answered. The questions that appeared for this one didn't answer mine.

I have a PC with:

- Windows 7 Professional
- AMD II x 2 B24 clocked at 3.0Ghz
- ATI Radeon HD 4200 ( I'm upgrading it. )
- 8GB RAM
- Does not support UEFI

I downloaded Ubuntu, used `Unetbootin` to extract the `.iso` files onto my 16GB `SanDisk Cruzer USB`, restarted my PC and pressed <kbd>F9</kbd> for the BIOS Boot Menu, selected `USB Device` and it just booted to Windows. (USB device *was* plugged in!)

I restarted my PC again and entered the BIOS Setup and ensured that the USB booted first.

Still nothing. I formatted my USB and used another PenDrive extractor, the one Ubuntu recommended, and still nothing.

*What am I doing wrong here?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Does your PC support UEFI? Do you see any error message? How much RAM do you have? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin has been broken for a while, the best way to create the USB now is to create it using Win32diskimager, the install process should then work.

Comment: If that worked, could you update the answer with accepting it or an upvote?